# Design/Architecture: web-socket one connection vs multiple connections

Tags: websocket, memcached

During a designing of a client/server architecture, is there any advantage to multiplexing multiple WEBSOCKET connections from the same process to the server (i.e. sharing one connection) vs opening one WEBSOCKET connection per thread/session in the client (as is typically done when connecting to memcached or database servers.)

I'm aware about the overhead associated with each connection (e.g. RAM ...). But expect to have less than 1K-10K at the most in each client side.

---

Specific use case:
Lets assume, I have a remote server with multiple sessions on one side, and on the other side I have multiple clients, each client will connect to a different session through the websocket server. 
In the remote server, there are 2 ways to implement it: (1) each session create its own websocket connection (2) all sessions will use same websocket connection.

From connection point of view, I like the sharing solution (one websocket connection to all sessions), because websocket server is limited by #of connections available (saving servers/scaling).

But from traffic/data speed/performance point of view, if a sessions will send lots of small packages through the connection, then, if we use one sharing connection, we will not be able to utilize the bandwidth (payload..../collect few small packages into one or split big package into small packages), because we may have to send different packages to different clients from different sessions, in this case, we will not be able to collect few packages (small packages) since they have different destination and from different sources!!, unless we will create "virtual connection" that manage each session data to maximize the speed, but this would create much implementation complexity!!!

Any other opinions?

Thanks,
JB.

Answer (score 18):

I think you should consider using a limited connection pool, like they do with Database connection architecture.

Another solution I would consider is a Pub/Sub database middleman such as Redis. This allows you to use existing solutions as well as easier scalability.

To the best of my understanding, both having a single connection and using a multitude of connections have their issues.

For example, one connection can send only one message at a time. A big enough message could block the connection... are you moving big data?

Many connections can cause an overhead that could be very expensive as well as introduce more chances for errors. Consider the following:

1. Creating new connections is very expensive, uses bandwidth, suffers from longer network delays and requires local resources and this is exactly what websockets allows us to avoid.
2. You will run into scalability issues. For instance, Heroku limits websocket connections to 600 per server, or at least they did so a short while back (and I think it's reasonable)... How will you connect all the servers together to one data-store?
3. Remember every OS has an open file limit and that websockets use the IO architecture (each one is an 'open-file', so that websockets are a limited resource).

Regarding traffic/data speed/performance, it is a question of server architecture... but I believe you will actually see a slight speed increase by using one connection (or a small pool of connections). It's important to remember that there isn't any effective multi-tasking when you need to send TCP/IP packets.

Also, with a limited number of connections (even with one connection), you will be able to benefit from the OS's packet joining feature that will allow you to send a number of websocket frames over one TCP/IP packet (unless you constantly flush the TCP/IP socket). You will actually waste more bandwidth with more connections - even disregarding the bandwidth used to open each new connection.

Just my 5 cents, we will all think differently, I'm sure.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks Myst, indeed, there are lots of questions to consider, and the solution is based on the requirement (what is more important...).

Comment: @Myst Would you know any particular rule of thumb used as to how many websocket connections should be used to still enjoy packet joining and other limited connection benefits while having better throughput than 1 connection? for example (# sessions)/3 or something?

Comment: @JonathanLee - the calculation should be similar to TCP/IP throughput, as the CPU overhead for parsing the packets is usually negligible relative to the network overhead. See this [TCP/IP throughput calculator](https://www.switch.ch/network/tools/tcp_throughput/) for example (there are many). Depending on your client and server TCP/IP buffer limits, you probably don't need another connection before you reach 13 Mbits/Sec (just shy of 2MB every second)... it's probably good enough for streaming a (compressed) full HD movie, but a 4K movie will need extra buffer for the server socket.